# "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of" error on RedHat/Centos 7.5 when I install Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, centos, redhat

I installed a LEMP stack on a Centos 7.5 to run a Drupal application.

PHP version needed is 7.2, installed using epel/remi repositories.

When all is done, and the application is correctly deployed, I get a "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of XX bytes exhausted (tried to allocate XXX bytes) in bla/bla/bla.php"

It seems to be a memory_limit issue, but it cannot be: PHP memory limit is set to 512M and the application runs correctly in any other environments (based on Debian). I tried also to reproduce this issue re-creating the stack on a centos:centos7.5 docker image, and all works well.

I think this could be a RedHat/Centos issue, maybe some OS parameters. Consider that I've also disabled Selinux.

Any idea?

Thx
Daniele

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/managing-site-performance-and-scalability/changing-php-memory-limits

Comment: Maybe there is more than one `php.ini` check the `phpinfo()` output to see which `php.ini` file is being used

Comment: @RiggsFolly there is only one php.ini file, and I'm correctly using it.

If I increase this value, I can see changes in the errors. I tried to set it at 1024, and I receive the same error.

Guys: this is NOT a memory_limit error. Otherwise I should have the same error also in the other environments.
And this is NOT an application error, otherwise I should have the same error also in the other environments.

I'm pretty sure this is problem related to CentOs/RedHat

Comment: Was that `1024` or `1024M` or did you try `1G` Or did you forget to compile PHP with `--enable-memory-limit`

Comment: @RiggsFolly maybe I found: it seems a problem with the symbolic links I used in my deploy procedure (based on Ansible). But it seems a problem related to RedHat/CentOs distros... I'm still scouting...

Answer (score 2):

If you are using centos 7 as server and php is 7.2
go to `/usr/local/php72/lib`
as root an find `memory_limit`
for drupal 8 you need to set `memory_limit`  at least `2048M`

```
memory_limit = 2048M
```